# How to implement pairwise hinge loss in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp

I'm trying to implement a pairwise hinge loss for two tensors which are both 200 dimensional. The goal is to use the cosine similarity of that two tensors as a scoring function and train the model with the pairwise hinge loss.

The model is accepting two text inputs and they have been converted to two 200 dimensional vectors. (The second text input is the correct label for the first text input).

Can anyone show me how to implement this in Keras?

```
def cosine_distance(vests):
    jd, jt = vests
    jd = K.l2_normalize(jd, axis=-1)
    jt = K.l2_normalize(jt, axis=-1)
    return -K.mean(jd * jt, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

def cos_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0],1)
```

Above are the code I have for the lambda layer to calculate the cosine similarity and jd is the first text input and jt is the second.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC(CMIIW), your model takes two input and output two tensors:

```
ip1, ip2 = Input(shape=(20,)), Input(shape=(20,))
backbone = Sequential()
backbone.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
backbone.add(Dense(200, activation='sigmoid'))
op1, op2 = backbone(ip1), backbone(ip2)
model = Model(inputs=[ip1, ip2], outputs=[op1, op2])
```

To calculate the cosine distance of these two output tensors, your loss function need to takes two inputs:

```
def cosine_distance(jd, jt):
    jd = K.l2_normalize(jd, axis=-1)
    jt = K.l2_normalize(jt, axis=-1)
    return -K.mean(jd * jt, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
```

And finally compile with this specific loss:

```
model.compile('sgd', loss=cosine_distance)
```